# How to compile Wget with OpenSSL?

Tags: linux, wget, https

I'm trying to compile Wget using SSL suppor OpenSSL but I can't find a way to configure it.(I'm new to Linux)

I already installed OpenSSL but wget it compiling by it default compiler gnutls as you can see:

```
wget -V
GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on linux-gnu.

-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls 
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/gnutls
```

Can someone explain me the process?

Comment: Do not put screenshots of terminal content in your question. Insert the text and format it as code.

Comment: @related  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817337/compiling-wget-with-static-linking-self-compiled-openssl-library-linking-issu

Answer (score 2):

Install wget using one of the defined below command:

```
sudo apt install wget
sudo yum wget
sudo pacman -S wget
```

Why you are compiling it?

If you need specific version you can compile it this way:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.8.2.tar.gz
tar xvzf wget-1.8.2.tar.gz
cd wget-1.8.2
./configure --with-openssl
make
make install
```

You can choose which wget you need. Here you have a list with many wget versions: [wget](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/)

Comment: I would **not** use `--prefix /usr` unless you wanna wreak havoc to your system.

Comment: Corrected. Anyway I know what I am doing, but most people are not sysadmins, so yes, you are right.

Comment: You need option `--with-ssl=openssl` (default is `gnutls`) and you'll probably also want to install the `libssl-dev` (Debian) or `openssl-devel` (CentOS)
package using your package manager. The latest version (currently 1.20.3) is [wget-latest.tar.gz](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz).

Answer (score 1):

What sysad&Freddy said above worked for me:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
tar xvzf wget-latest.tar.gz
cd wget-<insert version>
./configure --with-ssl=openssl
make
sudo make install
```